# Where are the JRuby native headers installed when installing with RVM?

Tags: rvm, jruby

I am using OS X 10.8, and I installed JRuby using RVM (`rvm install jruby`). I can see JRuby-1.7.6 is installed at ~/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.6, but I don't see ~/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.6/lib/native/include/ruby/ directory there. Later when I tried to build a native extension (`jruby -S gem install posix-spawn`), I got an error message saying that

```
~/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:14: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at ~/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.6/lib/native/include/ruby/ruby.h.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`posix-spawn` is only compatible with MRI Ruby, it could work with Rubinius but will not work with JRuby because it does not support C Extensions.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find a workaround to add C extensions to the latest JRuby. Finally hacked the gem code to use another lib instead of posix-spawn, it seems working under JRuby now.